# Wait till sound is finished and then play another sound

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a morse code audio player. I play each sound with this function:

```
function playSound(n: number): void{
if(n === 0){
    let sound = new Audio("../audio/short.mp3");
    sound.play();
}
else if(n === 1){
    let sound = new Audio("../audio/long.mp3");
    sound.play();
}
else{
    let sound = new Audio("../audio/break.mp3");
    sound.play();
}
```

I call it here:

```
for (let j = 0; j < nummers.length; j++){
       playSound(nummers[j]);
    }
```

But when I call this function multiple times the sound are playing in parallel. Who can I play one after another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)? This can give you the ability to wait before calling another function. At which point, the next function could play the next sound.

For example:

```
function playSound1() {
    let sound = new Audio("../audio/short.mp3");
    sound.play();

    setTimeout(playSound2, 1000); /* This is in milliseconds (so 1 second) -- you should change this to correspond with how long short.mp3 is */
}

function playSound2() {
    let sound = new Audio("../audio/long.mp3");
    sound.play();

    setTimeout(playSound3, 2000);
}

function playSound3() {
    let sound = new Audio("../audio/break.mp3");
    sound.play();
}

playSound1();
```

You could then add many more if you wanted, but this does imply that you know the precise length, which you should be able to access with `sound.duration`. So instead of `setTimeout(playeSound2, 1000);`, you could say `setTimeout(playSound2, sound.duration * 1000);`

You could also make this into a single function like you have by just calling to the function on different intervals (using `setTimeout` again). To give it your parameter `n`, you just add a third value into the `setTimeout` function:

```
playSound(1);
setTimeout(playSound, 1000, 2); /* will play the second sound after 1 second */
setTimeout(playSound, 2000, 3); /* plays the third sound 2 seconds after the second sound is played */
```

This is pretty much the same concept but uses your function instead.

***OP's Question Edit:*** "*Is there a way to do this without knowing how many sounds I have?*"

Yes! This would be a good time to use an array of sounds where you preload all the audios and then can play one at a time using the same concept but with an array instead.

In my following example I use a sum variable `prevSoundDurationSum` that counts how long the duration for each song is, so when you get to the next song you know how long you should wait before playing it.

**Example:**

```
playSound(sound) {
    sound.play();
}

let allSounds = [new Audio("../audio/short.mp3"), new Audio("../audio/long.mp3"), new Audio("../audio/break.mp3")];

let prevSoundDurationSum = 0;

for (let playsound = 0; playsound < allSounds.length; playsound++) {
    setTimeout(playSound, prevSoundDurationSum, allSounds[playsound]);

    /* Add to the sum */
    prevSoundDurationSum += allSounds[playsound].duration * 1000;
}
```

**Note an error from the previous version:** `.duration` functionality returns in seconds, so multiply by `1000` to get the milliseconds for the `setTimeout()` function.

Comment: is there a way to use this methode with out knowing how many sound I will have

Comment: Yes @HansPeter, I added another example about using an array of sounds, which you can then loop through using a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).